# How to understand a complicated random process

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I read a paper and it defines a r.p as following:

1. $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^k$
2. $\{h_i\}_{i=1}^n$   and  $\{g_j\}_{j=1}^k$   are two indep. sets of orthonormal r.v.'s
3. Define a r.p:
   [image]

---

Question:

**How to persuade myself that it is a r.p?**

---

My idea is that this r.p looks like
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
X_{x_1,y_1} &  X_{x_1,y_2} &  \cdots &   X_{x_1,y_k}    \\
X_{x_2,y_1} &  X_{x_2,y_2} &  \cdots &   X_{x_2,y_k}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
X_{x_n,y_1} &  X_{x_n,y_2}  &\cdots &   X_{x_n,y_k} 
\end{array}    $$

$X_{x_i,y_j}$ = the formula defined in 3. with $x_i \in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y_j \in\mathbb{R}^n$. 
Each row is a sample function and each column is a random variable.

Is this thinking correct?

Thanks!

Comment: If I am reading your formula correctly, you do not have a stochastic process. Specifically, given vectors $x,h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y,g \in \mathbb{R}^k$, the sum you've written is a real number. Then since $x,y$ are fixed and $h,g$ are random variables, $X$ is a random variable. $X$ could be a stochastic process if, say, $x$ or $y$ depended on time.

Comment: Before that this paper defines another center Gaussian process {$X_{ij}$}, i = 1,2,...,n. So I think if taking $y_j$ as time index then it should be a r.p. Is it feasible?

Comment: I guess that makes a certain amount of sense.